# React front-end token check for private routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jwt, token

I am currently looking at an example for token authentication for a react app with express back-end and I stumbled upon Jason Watmore's [React + Redux - JWT Authentication Tutorial & Example](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2017/12/07/react-redux-jwt-authentication-tutorial-example) blog entry on how to create a react-redux authentication front-end. In this, to render a private route, the front-end simply checks for the existence of a token and has the server verify with its routes.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

export const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={props => (
    localStorage.getItem('user')
      ? <Component {...props} />
      : <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location } }} />
  )} />
)
```

**Is the code above a valid way to render private routes** as he does mention that someone could go an insert a token into localStorage but the server will verify the request. My other way of approaching this was to have the private route verify the token asynchronously within the render function as such:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

export const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={(token, props) => (
    tokenAuthenticationRequest(token)
      ? <Component {...props} />
      : <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location } }} />
  )} />
)
```

However one of the issues I have run into was that React components need to use Suspense in order to load asynchronous functions.

Comment: While an asynchronous request is a valid scenario, to put it inside a route, it would mean that multiple API calls would be made, worse for nested routes. You can make this decision in the main file and pass it down as state to the `Route`